# Is instabot.py safe to use?

Tags: python, api, instagram-api, facebook-access-token, instagram-graph-api

I am unfamiliar with the instaboy.py python package. I am wondering if there are any security issues with this package like possibly getting information leaked. I am wondering how does the API work if there are a lot of people using this package. Wouldn't you need your own personal Instagram API token? I am confused by the whole concept and if anyone could explain even just a little bit it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bots are now easily detected by Instagram. Your account could be banned for 3 days, 7 days, 30 days or definitively if Instagram detects too many attempts
Usually bots simulate a browser via Sellenium and then create a "browse like a human" bot to create likes, follow, unfollow, etc.